# Asking an slightly related (but off topic) question on another persons question

Tags: support, questions, comments

I have given an answer on a question ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33757139/4811060)) and there is someone on the other answer who has asked a question not relating to the OP's question.

When I pointed out the rules for questions, the person made it seem like I was trying to make it personal.

Can someone point me to the rules/guidance on this for support or *back-up*?

**EDIT**
Amended link to actual answer comments are on, before it went to my answer which was wrong

Comment: What you could have done was to flag the comment(s) as "other" and then give an explanation. Although, there could be another option added to it such as "not related to the question". ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii-, I did that for one, the commenter made what I felt was a personal attack and a bit of a *dig* at me, so straight up this was flagged

Comment: By my own experiences, you inform/ask the person to remove their comment saying it's not related. If they don't after say... 5 minutes, flag the comment(s), but don't get into a discussion with them. I've learned that lesson myself in my early days on Stack. Call it additional "experience" on top of "coding" experience. Arguing usually never solves things, same thing goes between neighbours and their yapping dog(s). *Cheers*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rules are simple - a new question belongs in a new question (topic). Even if the new question is related, it belongs to a new question. StackOverflow is a Q&A site, not a discussion forum. A similar problem is that of the [chameleon question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions), though that pertains to a situation where the OP constantly adds new questions.

I couldn't find a reference in the help center, but one of the auto-generated comments in the Low Quality posts review queue is noteworthy in this respect:

> If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the Ask Question button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context.

Comment: It's not the OP, there is an answer beyond mine that is downvoted and another person is asking for what is almost (by the appearance) a tutorial on the answer. Personally I do not mind helping further, but when someone asks something unrelated then points at me and says "it's not about you", I find that an attack both on the SO rules and myself

Comment: If even the OP is not allowed to ask a new question in his/her own question,  why would another user be allowed to do this?

Comment: The question from the OP directly fell as corresponding to the original question, where the commenter wanted something else, I was happy to expand my answer to give this extra for the OP, but the commenter was off topic by a long while